Multi Nox Player Opens only Nox player at first position
We are using NoxPlayer for our project, which requires us to open and close NoxPlayer at specific times. This process works fine with a single instance of NoxPlayer running on port 62001. However, we are encountering several issues when attempting to open a second instance, NoxPlayer2:
We need to determine a unique identifier that can be used to open NoxPlayer1 and NoxPlayer2. Currently, our code only opens the default NoxPlayer.
We want to assign a permanent and static port number to each NoxPlayer instance, such as:
NoxPlayer1: 62001
NoxPlayer2: 62002
Occasionally, we experience issues when connecting with ADB commands.
Please assist us in resolving these issues.
I have tried opening Nox player in Python code via instance name , pid, vmpid and IMEI no but it always opens up first nox player.
Here is the code
    def open_nox(instance_name):
    try:
    print(f"Launching NoxPlayer instance with name: {instance_name}")
    command = \[nox_path, 'launch', f'-name:{instance_name}'\]
    print(f"Command: {' '.join(command)}")  # Debug output

    # Launch the Nox instance
    process = subprocess.Popen(command)
    time.sleep(20)  # Allow time for Nox to start
    return process
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to open NoxPlayer instance with name: {instance_name}: {e}")
    return None

